# Message along with file response

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need a way to add a warning message to file response.

```
[HttpPost("Export")]
public async Task<FileResult> Export()
{
    (byte[] data, string message) = await _searchExportService.ExcelExport();

    if (data == null)
    {
        // Return error message without sending a file
        return ...;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
    {
        // Somehow add message to response
    }

    return File(data, "my-content-type");
}
```

I thought about http headers, found a [warning http header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Warning), but it seems to be deprecated soon. I'm not sure whether custom headers are appropriate for this or not and wondering if there are any standard ways to do it.

I don't want to Base64 encode my payload due to performance impact.

The message can be localized, so Unicode support for message is required.

Comment: Just use custom header

Comment: Use `Response.Headers.Add("message", "xxx");` before `return File(data, "my-content-type");` as  `Alexander` said.